# Cannot overwrite file with JSCH SCP

Tags: java, scp, jsch

First, sorry for my poor english ...

I'm using JSCH to upload files via SCP and it works well.

My only problem is that when the destination file already exists and belongs to another user, I can't overwrite the file, even if i'm in the same group of the file and the permissions are set to 664.

The message return by the server is :

```
set mode: Operation not permitted
```

It seems that JSCH set the permissions after the upload, and fail because I'm not the owner of the file. Here is the part of my code :

```
// Send "C0644 filesize filename", where filename should not include '/'
int filesize = (int) localFile.length();
String command = "C0644 " + filesize + " ";
command += localFile.getName();
command += "\n";
```

Is there any way to tell JSCH not to change permissions ?

I tried to remove C0644 in the command but of course it failed :)

And unfortunately I didn't find any documentation of JSCH.

Comment: Ok I found a workaround using ChannelSftp instead of SCP, like here : http://kodehelp.com/java-program-for-uploading-file-to-sftp-server/

Comment: It did not work for me.  Permission Denied even when using channel.put(path, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE).  Overwriting works on the same account with filezilla.  Do you remember wich version of JSch were you using, or maybe some code ?